# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 - Power button action "Interactive" doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, laptop, asus, ubuntu-gnome

I want the confirm dialog when I press the power button. It worked in 15.10. I tried tweaks tool and dconf editor, neither work. In dconf there are 2 entries one doesn't work, the other doesn't have an option for "interactive". Tweaks tool has the option, but it doesn't work.

Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS on Asus zenbook ux305

Thank you

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: I think [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/827475) has an explanation for the issue