# Change “power-button-action” comand for “interactive” option in GNOME 3.20

Tags: shutdown, ubuntu-gnome, 16.10

I have a question that is very similar to 
[Change "power-button-action" comand for "hibernate" option in GNOME 3.18](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762268/change-power-button-action-comand-for-hibernate-option-in-gnome-3-18?newreg=480b2497a5024a589a69c9d990cb69f9)
, however the fix that is proposed there does not solve my issue...

I generally use the power button as a shutdown shortcut. I'd rather do that than navigating all the way to the upper-top menu...

However I like to have a confirmation popup...

In short, I would like to configure the 'interactive' way...

...but since I recently installed GNOME 3.20, I found out that the only available actions for power button press are : "nothing", "suspend" and "hibernate".

In `dconf-editor`, there are two entries for this:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action
```

The first one contains all options (hibernate, `interactive`, suspend, poweroff, nothing,..),

...but the second one contains only three (hibernate, suspend, nothing).

**Why isn't there an interactive option ? Can someone point me to a technical reason why it could not be proposed there ?**

**How can I set it on y own ?**

By the way...I also noticed that `lid-close-ac-action` can be configured to `interactive`...

... I understand that it may be useful on a docking station, but I can't help making fun of the fact that once the lid is closed on the keyboard *(and therefore none of them are visible or accessible any longer in most cases)*, then I will be promped for a choice... How convenient !

Answer (score 0):

As this question was never answered, for future reference, it appears that the `interactive` option was dropped in Gnome >3.18 (or 3.20). Details referenced in the following related bugs and discussions that continue to persist into 2017:

- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=755953
- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781817

Do a page search on "interactive" for specific details.

Rich